# icCube - Monitoring: incremental load - set up

Tags: monitoring, iccube

I have some trouble with incremental load: it is not showing any changes of the data.

What am I doing?

1. schema is loaded
2. changes inside the origin data table
3. incremental load is performing with the help of the schedular
4. "fresh time start" and "refest time end" of the schema is viewable
5. no error occured

I can not see any changes in the reports after an incremental load was performed. After a full load the changes are visible.

My set up:

- builder schema: incremental load is activated
- builder schema data source:

  - incr. load strategy: icnremental load
  - incr. load column: incremental_id (datatype is long)
- monitoring schemas schedular:

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or what I can try?

Cheers Joe

log:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incremental load works if I add an Incr. Load SQL Statement within the schema.
Schema -> Data Integration ->Data Source -> Your Source -> -> Your table -> field incr. load SQl

Answer (score 0):

> I can not see any changes in the reports after an incremental load was performed. After a full load the changes are visible.

Assuming you have new data in the schema, you might have forgot to setup the "Refresh Period" of the report.

Otherwise, check the log file that will mention that new data has been loaded for the given schema during the incremental load. You can then check within the MDX IDE that new data is available.

Hope that helps.

[edit: the error was due a SQL query badly generated ([www](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-279))]

Comment: Hallo Marc, the report was refreshed but still there was no new data. I checked the log file but it didnt throw an error. cheers Joe

Comment: Does the log file show any new data being loaded during the incremental load?

Comment: I couldnt find an error inside the log. The  pictures above shows the logfiles. Maybe you can help me. There are a few lines missing (the select statement).

Comment: From the logs, no data has been loaded. Ensure there is new data in the table and the incr. load column is well defined: in the example you should have new row with incr.load-col with values greater than: 263189 (aka. save points).

Comment: If I start a full load after an incremental load the new data is shown. That means there was already new data available.

Comment: Then if you are sure there is a bug report a bug ( issues @ icCube.com )

Comment: Hey Marc, I tried to write a mail to issues at iccube.com but this mail is not existitng. Thereafter I wrote a mail to contact at iccube.com and asked them to forward the mail to the appropriate department. So far I got no respond. Do you have another mail adress for reporting the bug? Cheers

Comment: Sorry my mistake... support @ icCube.com